# How to change parts of the line in AndroidCharts

Tags: android, charts

I use [AndroidCharts](https://github.com/HackPlan/AndroidCharts) for drawing Line graph. But i want to change **part of line** color or set part of line to a dotted line. How can i do this? Thanks!

Comment: Seems there is not default method to do so..you need to modify the class https://github.com/HackPlan/AndroidCharts/blob/master/AndroidCharts/src/main/java/im/dacer/androidcharts/LineView.java to achieve that

Comment: @Akshay, can you help me modify it???

Comment: Where exactly do you want to change color and draw dotted line??any event trigger?

Comment: @Akshay, for example, i have ListData for 100 element. I create graph for this data. But i want For ending 50 elements set dotter line style.

Comment: @Akshay, or for count of some data

Comment: @Tomas...still figuring that out..i had a project like that

Comment: @Akshay, can you help me write method for my task?

Comment: yes.. You post your code what you have done.. I'll tell you what to change or how to proceed